# SQL: good database design for cards?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

This is a question about model design for SQL or SQLite.

Suppose you have some card game which has many reusable cards and the players make decks out of those card (e.g. MtG)

Naturally you do not want to make new instances of the cards for every deck that a user might create. That would have a lot of redundancy.

Thus there should be a "master" card (with all of its associated info).

My question is then, how to best integrate the cards (and quantity there of) in a given deck?

(I am not actually making this database, it just highlights the design of having a user having any number collections of multiple items in various quantities from some general stock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have three tables: One table has the data on the cards (name, cost, etc.). Another table has decks (deck name, creator, etc.). And another table has the cards in the deck (deck_cards) (linking card_id to deck_id with quantity).

EDIT: addendum: This is the same set up (and rationale) as the classic go-to example used in all database design primers: products, orders, and order-line-items. The only piece missing is "customers" (which could be added if you wanted to link decks to players or deck-builders).

Comment: That works, but I still find it less than ideal given that the table `deck_cards` only adds one field, and that from an admin stand-point, one has to create the deck by first making sure the cards in are in table `cards`, then making the deck and description, and finally populate the deck in `deck_cards`.  I am not actually making this database, it was just an example I thought of emphasizing the problem I am having

Comment: If you're using SQL, then you are asking about someone making a database, even if it's not you. So the answers will naturally assume making a database.

This paradigm (three tables) is certainly more ideal than not using the deck_cards table. Unless you don't require any information about the decks at all except for their cards, in which case you can omit the decks tables and rename deck_cards as decks (I doubt this is a good idea, as you'll eventually want to refer to the decks by something other than their deck_id).

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine something like:

Cards - Table containing card details

```
Card_ID    Card_Name    Card_Dmg   Card_Attribute   Card_Health
   123      Fire Mage     20            Fire             100
   345      Water Man      6            Water            200
   037      Earth Dwarf   10            Earth            150
```

Players - Table containing Player details

```
Player_ID     Player_ForeName     Player_Surname
    1             Fred               Smith
```

Player_Cards - Table detailing the players deck, with a new row for each card they own, e.g:

```
Player_ID     Card_ID
   1            123
   1            345
   1            037
```

Comment: If saving specific Deck information is important, then add in the Deck table per the other answer.